# Send "AdminMessage" using PHP on GAE?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to send an email via [AdminMessage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/api.mail.AdminMessage#%5Cgoogle%5Cappengine%5Capi%5Cmail%5CAdminMessage) using PHP on Google App Engine.

I can send a "normal" email using [Message](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/api.mail.Message#%5Cgoogle%5Cappengine%5Capi%5Cmail%5CMessage), but I am not able to send "admin" emails.

Has anyone managed to send admin emails? Could someone share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send admin messages using PHP.

All you need to do is replace your usage of the **Message** class with **AdminMessage** in your source code for sending a *normal* message, and don't specify any to addresses.

Comment: Thanks. This is the code for anyone else who needs it:  
'  
    <?php
    
    require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
    use google\appengine\api\mail\AdminMessage;
    
    $mail_options = [
        "sender" => "adminEmail@example.com",
        "subject" => "subject",
        "textBody" => "body"
    ];
    
    try {
        $message = new AdminMessage($mail_options);
        $message->send();
        echo "Thankyou for your Message";
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        echo "error" . $e;
    }
    
    echo "\n\n\n end of script";
    
    ?>
'

Comment: I was looking for examples like you a few months ago, but AdminMessage is not documented by Google, even though they give you a quota for them. The only *bug* I found with them was that because Admin messages are sent to all users who have permissions on the project, every time I sent one, 3 actually got sent one to me, and the others to service accounts.